# How was Jesus conceived?

Tags: life-of-jesus

The Bible describes some people as being created or formed, in [Genesis 1:27](http://www.usccb.org/bible/genesis/1/27) and [Genesis 2](http://www.usccb.org/bible/genesis/2):7,22:

> 1:27 God created mankind in his image;
>   in the image of God he created them;
>   male and female* he created them.
>
> 2:7 then the LORD God formed the man out of the dust of the ground and blew into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man became a living being.
>
> 2:22 The LORD God then built the rib that he had taken from the man into a woman. When he brought her to the man,

But usually people are conceived through intercourse, as mentioned in [Genesis 4:1](http://www.usccb.org/bible/genesis/4):

> 1 The man had intercourse with his wife Eve, and she conceived and gave birth to Cain, saying, “I have produced a male child with the help of the LORD.”

Were either of these the case with Jesus? In what way was Jesus conceived?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even Mary had the same question in her mind when Angel said to her:

> Luke: 1:31 Listen: You will become pregnant and give birth to a son, and you will name him Jesus.

And she immediately asked a similar question as yours:

> Luke: 1:34 Mary said to the angel, “How will this be, since I have not had sexual relations with a man?”

And the answer is:

> Luke:1:35 The angel replied, “The Holy Spirit will come upon you, and the power of the Most High will overshadow you. Therefore the child to be born will be holy; he will be called the Son of God.

It is sometime better to reconcile to the fact that,  we do not  have mind of God to understand His ways and so accept some things as Mary did. If we were to know everything God does and how God carry out His business then He would not be any different from us.

Answer (score 2):

Jesus was [conceived through the Holy Spirit](http://bible.cc/matthew/1-18.htm), as is testified in the scriptures.

It implies that a supernatural conception happened. Beyond this, we can't draw conclusions where the scriptures are silent.